# Can someone recommend an asp.net reporting package that allows users to define their own reports?

Tags: asp.net, reporting

We are adding a reporting page to one of our asp.net applications, and one of the requirements is the user be able to customize their reports.  CrystalReports won't work because we can't guarantee the user will have a local copy in which to modify a report.  MS Reports doesn't seem to support what we want either.  Is there a package out there with an interactive designer which we could embed in our application?  Or some other option that maybe we've overlooked?

The input for the report will be an XML file.

Thanks

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the DevExpress reporting and grid packages?  What I did was to create a reporting page with a variety of data selection fields at the top.  The user could customize the selection criteria and then simply re-run the report.  This provides end-user *selection criteria* customization but not layout customization.

You might also want to look at their grid and pivot-grid packages. It is very easy to customize the grids - even for the end-user.  If they rearrange the fields or pull them into a grouping area, that customizes the presentation.  These can very easily be exported as a report (PDF), Word document or Excel document as well.  We also created an interface that pulled or deleted fields from the grid as well.  Thus we have *end-user selection* and *returned field* customization as well as grouping and summaries.

The one thing that no one provides, as far as I know, is a full-fledged end-user reporting tool that provides selection criteria, returned field AND formatting customization.

Answer (score 0):

How about Microsoft Reporting Services?  The user can be given access to an activeX control that will allow them to modify the .rdl files.  They are interactive and built for the web.

You can also integrate it into Sharepoint.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that the data source will be an XML file.  We are doing this because the data presented in the report will be post-processed from data stored in the database.